Why are log tables used instead of reciprocal tables to speed up division?
I'm trying to optimize some SuperH assembly. The div is significantly slower than the mul. I'm considering testing a reciprocal table + mul and compare the speed of that to a div for my application. I understand that the memory access for the table will be slow too, but still might be faster than a div.
However, when researching this, I came across some info talking about using log + exp tables for this purpose, rather than a reciprocal table.
I understand how log + exp can be used instead of division, but why take this approach instead of a reciprocal table? If you use log + exp, you need twice the memory, and worse, twice the number of memory accesses. (Although I suppose if you interleave them correctly you can load both the needed log + exp values into the same cache line in a single memory access)
What's the advantage that log + exp tables provide over a simple reciprocal table?

If you use a reciprocal table, you still have to perform a multiplication in order to implement division.  Log/exp tables, on the other hand, turn division into subtraction.  I'm not familiar with the SuperH family, but I can easily believe that subtraction is sufficiently faster than multiplication to make up for the additional table lookup.

Gotcha! On the SuperH, the mul is 3 cycles, compared with 1 for subtraction. In my mind, 3 cycles isn't so bad, compared with the ~32+ cycles needed for division. I hadn't considered that other architectures might have a mul that is much slower than a subtraction, hence log + exp tables being more common. And I suppose if I'm trying to optimize as much as possible, might as well try the log + exp tables and see how it compares to the reciprocal table. Thank you!
